# Find Exception type

Tags: java, exception

If I have the following code:

```
try {
    //some offensive code     
} catch (Exception e) {
    String type = //get type of e
    Assert.fail(type + " thrown.");
}
```

Is there a way I can get the type of the Exception so I can output:

```
NullReferenceException thrown.
InvalidOperationException thrown.
OutOfMemoryException thrown.
```

etc?  I know I can switch on different types using instanceOf(), but that assumes I'm expecting a specific type.

FWIW, I know this specific code chunk is terrible and violates many of the [best practices](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) suggested by Eric Lippert.  I'm just curious if there is a way to determine Exception type at runtime.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can call `e.getClass().getName()` to get class name.

`getName()` returns the name including package, e.g. `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

`getSimpleName()` returns just a class name, e.g. `OutOfMemoryError`.

See javadoc for [Class object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) to see all info you can get.